# How to add icon for child node?

Tags: android, treeview

I use this [lib](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView). I want add icon for any child. But i don't know how i can do it.please help me.thanks any body.i read sample but ..this is my code.please read link

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();

 final    TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("Melk");
    final TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode("Build_1");
    TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("Build_2");

    TreeNode child_1 = new TreeNode("Aparteman_1");
    TreeNode child_3 = new TreeNode("Aparteman_2");

    TreeNode child_4 = new TreeNode("Senfi_1");
    TreeNode child_5 = new TreeNode("Senfi_2");

    child_1.addChildren(child_4, child_5);
    child0.addChildren(child_1, child_3);
    parent.addChildren(child0, child1);

    root.addChild(parent);
    Button del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.del);

 parent.setClickListener(new TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value) {

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }
 });

    LinearLayout containerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.m);
    AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getApplicationContext(), root);
    containerView.addView(tView.getView());

}
}
```

post edited.i need your help.

Comment: Post your code...something that you have tried??

Comment: @Akshay thanks. i add icon for any item.but don't any space between parent node with child node. please help in this section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use custom adapter as it use for default android listview only difference is to extend TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder and overwrite createNodeView
this is a structure

```
public class MyHolder extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<IconTreeItem> {
    ...
    @Override
    public View createNodeView(TreeNode node, IconTreeItem value) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_profile_node, null, false);
        TextView tvValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.node_value);
        tvValue.setText(value.text);

        return view;
    }

    public static class IconTreeItem {
        public int icon;
        public String text;
    }
}
```

for more information this tutorial will help you on how use custom adapter 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: thanks for your help.but in my project, between note don't any space.child beside parent node.how i can do it?

Comment: sorry nothing has been found so far, can you explain why using this library and what's a purpose ?